# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContexte.xml]

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, configuration, oracle11g, xml

I have this problem !

```
 java.lang.AssertionError: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContexte.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: UP_GAB] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
        at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:91)
        at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:43)
        at com.bits.gabrent.TestJPA.test(TestJPA.java:21)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:76)
        at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

this is my applicationContexte File :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">
<!--
<bean id="datasource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value= "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value= "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:8080:gab"></property>
        <property name="username" value= "issam"></property>
        <property name="password" value= "admin123" ></property> -->

        <bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="user" value="issam"/>
        <property name="password" value="admin123"/>



</bean>

<bean id= "persistenceUnitManager" class= "org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
        <property name= "persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
        <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
        </property>
        <property name= "defaultDataSource" ref= "dataSource"></property>
 </bean>

<bean id= "entityManagerFactory" class= "org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name= "persistenceUnitManager" ref= "persistenceUnitManager"></property>
<property name= "persistenceUnitName" value= "UP_GAB"></property>
</bean>  




<bean id="transactionManager" class= "org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name= "entityManagerFactory" ref= "entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

</beans>
```

My persistence.xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd ">
  <persistence-unit name="UP_GAB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
        <property name= "hibernate.show_sql" value= "true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="issam"/>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin123"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I visited some Questions that may already have the answer but i don't found the solution
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Plz i need your help !

Comment: I'm not sure <property name= "persistenceUnitName" value= "UP_GAB"></property> is correct in your applicationContext.xml. try with <property name= "persistence-unit" value= "UP_GAB"></property>

Comment: Are you tryng to use a real `EntityManager` inside of a JUnit test? I don't think you're going to be able to make that happen. Can you please post your test code? I think you may be looking to mock that out.